# If ... else conditional statements in CSS stylesheet processed as PHP

Tags: php, html, css, apache, conditional-statements

I'm processing a CSS stylesheet as PHP by including the following at the top of my CSS file:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
?>
```

My CSS stylesheet (style.css) is called like this:

```
<style type="text/css">@import url("style.css") only screen and (min-device-width: 321px), only print;</style>
```

I have altered my Apache config file in the following way to enable the CSS file to be processed by the PHP engine:

```
<FilesMatch "^.*?common.*?$">
SetHandler php5-script
</FilesMatch>
```

In my CSS file, beneath the  header, is regular CSS content with the occasional php snippet, e.g.

...

```
<?php echo "* {margin: 10px; padding: 10px;}"; ?>

html
{
    background-color: #FFF;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

The above works fine, however if I try to include a php conditional statement I run into problems. For example, the following:

```
<?php
echo "* {";
if ($fixed_navigation_Home == "none") {echo "display: none;";}
else {echo "display: block;";}
echo "}";
?>
```

... produces only:

```
* {
}
```

... instead of one of the two style rules requested in the PHP.

Is anyone able to advise me what might be going wrong? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Do you've this `$fixed_navigation_Home` variable?

Comment: Yes, it's:
$fixed_navigation_Home = (string) "none";

Comment: Try refreshing the browser cache ;)

Comment: Yes, did that a number of times. Also, tried <link> instead of <style>, tried renaming css file to style.php, without success.

Comment: code is ok so clear your cashe ctrl+shfit+del or ctrl + F5. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops ...

The problem was my variable $fixed_navigation_Home which was declared by a controller file. Thanks to Mr Alien for drawing my attention to it.

The problem, I now realise, is that web pages are stateless: once the PHP processor has processed the page variables are destroyed. Consequently, my variable was not being 'remembered' since the style sheet is called by the browser *after* the page is generated.

Declaring the variable as a global did not help, for the reason given above. For those interested in the issue there are other pages which explain how to resolve the 'pass variable between pages' problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726352/using-php-variables-across-different-files

[Number of ways to share a variable defined in one PHP file among all the files of a website / application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017064/number-of-ways-to-share-a-variable-defined-in-one-php-file-among-all-the-files-o)

[Using PHP variables on multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224173/using-php-variables-on-multiple-pages)

Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

use this

help you out.......

`

echo "'* {'";

if ($fixed_navigation_Home == "none") {echo "'display: none;'";}

else {echo "'display: block;'";}

echo "'}'";

?>`