# Show/Hide if php variable it's true

Tags: php, html, mysqli

**This is my html code:**

```
<div id="view" class="login-box animated fadeInUp"<?php if ($reg===true){?>style="display:none"<?php } ?>>

        </div>

        <div id="popup"<?php if ($reg===false){?>style="display:none"<?php } ?>>
        </div>
```

**This is part of my php code:**

```
<?php
 ob_start();
 session_start();
error_reporting( ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE );

 $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','slide-uploader');

 if ( !$conn ) {
  die("Connection failed : " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }

 $error = false;
 $reg = false;

 /*Verifico i campi della form*/
 if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {


  $email = trim($_POST['user_email']);
  $email = strip_tags($email);
  $email = htmlspecialchars($email);
  $mailValidation = explode('@',$email)[1];
  $matricola = trim($_POST['user_matricola']);
   $name = ucfirst(explode('.',$email)[0]);
   $surname = ucfirst(preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', explode('@',explode('.',$email)[1]))[0]);
   $queryS = "SELECT * FROM studente WHERE Matricola ='$matricola'";
   $resS = mysqli_query($conn,$queryS);
   $count = mysqli_num_rows($resS);
   if($count<1){
     $query = "INSERT INTO studente (Matricola, Nome, Cognome, User) VALUES('$matricola','$name','$surname','$email')";
     $res = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
   }else{
     some code...
   }

   if ($res) {
    some code...
    unset($email);
    $reg = true;
    some code...
   } else {
     some code...
   }
  }
 }
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

I log the user and then return to the previous page (`window.history.go (-1)`) but `$reg` does not seem to be set.

As I should do to set the $reg variable in the html page?
The html page and the php page are two separate files.

Should I use variable `$ _SESSION`?

Comment: When you say `$reg variable in the html page?` do you mean a .html file? PHP can't run in a html file.

Comment: @Andreas It is actually possible to configure your server to parse .html-files as PHP. But it's not recommended.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this.

Comment: @StuntHacks That sounds like a very strange idea. Can't really see the point of that. I mean you only have to rename the file from .html to .php

Comment: Did you mean [Using PHP variables on multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/224173/367456)? (and similar)

Comment: @Andreas I know. And I don't know why one would do that. Just wanted to state, that it's indeed possible.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to fully understand what your website is supposed to do, but if you just want to hide/show html content depending on whether a variable is `true` or `false`, you can do that with a logic similar to this:

```
if ( $var ) //$var is true; display content
{
    ?>
        <div>Your html content that is supposed to be shown</div>
    <?php
}
```

You can even add an `else`, to show different content if it is not `true`.

```
if ( $var ) //$var is true; display content
{
    ?>
        <div>Your html content that is supposed to be shown</div>
    <?php
}
else
{
    ?>
        <div>A different html content</div>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have used "display:none" for both true and false situations. You can try "display:block;" if $reg is true (also include a blank space before *style* in both the places)

```
<div id="view" class="login-box animated fadeInUp" <?php if ($reg===true){?> style="display:block;"<?php } ?>>

    </div>

<div id="popup"<?php if ($reg===false){?> style="display:none"<?php } ?>>
    </div>
```